# Understanding Constructor Injection in Simple XML

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I want to create an inline list in XML. Something like this:

```
<numbers>
<phone>1234</phone>
<phone>5678</phone>
<phone>3456</phone>
</numbers>
```

The tutorial [here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#immutable) highlights how it can be done.

Now, I have no idea about how to deal with

```
public Order(@Attribute(name="name") String name, 
             @Element(name="product") String product)
```

or

```
public OrderManager(@ElementList(name="orders") List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
```

I have never worked with lists in Java.

My case:
A database, upon querying, will fill up an array `phone_numbers[x]`. How am I supposed to generate the XML file like above using the values in the array and Constructor Injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you had a class `PhoneNumbers` like so:

```
@Root
public class PhoneNumbers {
    @ElementArray(name="numbers", entry = "phone")
    private String[] phones;

    public PhoneNumbers(String[] phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
    }
}
```

There is no need in this case to convert to a `List`.

```
String[] phone_numbers= new String[] { "1234", "5678" }; // populate from DB instead
PhoneNumbers numbers = new PhoneNumbers(phone_numbers);

// to serialize
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
serializer.write(numbers, System.out);
```

This will print out the following XML:

```
<phoneNumbers>
   <numbers length="2">
      <phone>1234</phone>
      <phone>5678</phone>
   </numbers>
</phoneNumbers>
```

There is no way for the Simple framework to NOT print a root element.  So you could String strip the root element if you absolutely need to just serialize the `numbers` element.

That's it!

Comment: Thanks! So this is basically [Reading an array of elements](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#array), right?

Comment: That's absolutely right.  The `@ElementList` annotation has this handy concept called inline, which would discard the root element, but does not have the ability to rename the entries to 'phone'.  `@ElementArray` can rename the entries but has no inline concept.  It would be nice if they created a hybrid of the two...

Comment: One more thing. What about a case in which the array size is 10 but the DB populates it with only 5 values?
I suppose in that case we'll get blank tags for the rest 5. Any way to counter that?

Comment: Don't create an array with a fixed size to begin with; size your array according to the number of rows returned from the DB.

Comment: It doesn't have to be dynamic, just sized according to the number of elements you are going to unwrap from the DB.  If you don't know, you can use an `ArrayList` initially, then just call `list.toArray(new String[]{})` to convert it to a fixed `String` array.

Comment: Ofcourse :) I can query the DB and find the exact number of indexes. 
Thank you so much for the help!